# IOS/Objective-C: Send date to server using JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsjsonserialization

I would like to send a date/time (for an event calendar) using JSON to a server.  Once on the server, I would like it to be in the local time of the sender.

Since JSONSerialization does not support date object, I have been sending a Unix time stamp.  The problem is once in this form, the information about the user's time zone seems to be lost.

Is there a way to adjust the unix time stamp to reflect the user's time zone.  Or can anyone suggest a better way to NSJsonserialize a date?

Code below produces a unix time stamp but I want to save it on server as something like `2015-10-26 18:49:37`

```
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
CFTimeInterval startDate = [date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;
NSString *dateStarted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f+0800)/", startDate];
```

Comment: Before serializing the timestamp, add or subtract the offset from local time to UTC (not GMT).

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using full [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) syntax with the local time offset included from a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) timestamp.

`2015-11-04T09:20:22+00:00`

Getting an ISO-8601 date and timestamp from an NSDate is quite straight-forward, but you might want to look at a library for tips, if this is all new to you.

https://github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601

Comment: Do you need to download this library to do the conversion?

Comment: @user12345 If you take a look, specifically, at [github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/blob/master/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/CATEGORY_NSString%2BNSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/NSString%2BNSDateFormatter_ISO_8601.m](https://github.com/clearbrian/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/blob/master/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/NSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/CATEGORY_NSString%2BNSDateFormatter_ISO_8601/NSString%2BNSDateFormatter_ISO_8601.m) then you should have the key part you need for the client end. Server side, you'll need to decode it, obviously, from a string back into a date object.